# How to place an exported view into a specific location of another exported view?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am trying to create a toolbar by using two exported views. First view has button A, D, E and second view has button B, C. I want to create toolbar by placing both view into a new view. Problem is how to place second View inside first View after Button A.

So, Arrangement of button should be like

> A,B,C,D,E (Expected Arrangement)

Here's the working code for placing it side by side i.e.

> A,D,E,B,C

This is the user control where both views will be placed
**ToolbarView.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Dummy.Views.ToolbarView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"                                          
         xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"                         
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width ="0.5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width ="0.5*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ContentControl  prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RegionForFirstView"/>
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RegionForSecondView"/>
</Grid>
```

This is the code which will get the exported views and construct Toolbar:

```
        ToolbarView toolbarView = new ToolbarView();
        var scopedRegionManager = _myRegionManager.CreateRegionManager();
        RegionManager.SetRegionManager(toolbarView, scopedRegionManager);
        navParams.Add("regionManager", scopedRegionManager);
        scopedRegionManager.RequestNavigate("RegionForFirstView", "ExportedView1", navParams);
        scopedRegionManager.RequestNavigate("RegionForSecondView", "ExportedView2", navParams);
        ToolbarContent = toolbarView;
```

Answer (score 1):

The default region adapter for the content control cannot do this.

You have two options:

1. Create the toolbar region in an items control and make a view for each button and give it an index that's used to put the buttons in correct order
2. Get the buttons from a custom service that manages the ordering and show them in the content control using a view that contains an items control

If the buttons are static and determined by configuration only, I'd go for option two, because it's trivially easy. If the buttons change dynamically, I guess that the first option makes more sense. If you do not need to remove buttons dynamically, that is, because you cannot un-navigate a view from a region.